# Spec for class method - preserving order and returns an ActiveRecord relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec, rspec-rails

Pretty new on Rails and currently learning out how to tackle class methods, scope and spec...
Initially this was written as a scope in a model but it seems a bit bloated so I've taken it out and made it into class method like below:

```
class OrderedByIds

  scope :for_ids_with_order, lambda { |ids|
    order = sanitize_sql_array(
      ["position((',' || id::text || ',') in ?)", ids.join(',') + ',']
    )
    where(id: ids).order(order)
  }

end
```

# usage:

```
 OrderedByIds.for_ids_with_order([1, 3, 2])
```

What's the best way to unit test for this class method?

Comment: I don't understand what you've done. This used to be a method in a model, and now you've moved it into *another class*? How do you expect this to work? Can you provide more context? Based on the limited information you've provided, I don't think this makes sense -- you could move the method into a **module**, which gets `include`d into the model, but I don't know how you expect to use it as a standalone class like this.

Comment: You can test it just like any other method. For example, `expect(MyModel.for_ids_with_order).to eq (...)`. But again, without knowing some wider context of how this method is being used, I can't possibly write a working test case.

Comment: “class method” doesn't mean that you move a block of code into its own class. It means that you define a method on a class rather than on the instances of a class (see [method scopes](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Scope)). To extract parts of your class into separate modules, Rails provides [`ActiveSupport::Concern`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html)

Comment: @Stefan Initially, this is the scope usage and how do I make a class method?http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/653c0

Comment: @drifterOcean19 the "method scopes" link in my comment above contains an example of a class method. You usually just write `def self.method_name` within the class body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really Unit test this, because it's tightly coupled with the database.
So Rails model test are not really unit tests.

So with that out of the way, you can test it and it's pretty simple. (I'll assume you're using [FactoryBot](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md) and your rspec is [Aggregating failures](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-9/docs/aggregating-failures) )

```
let!(:order) { create(:order) }
let!(:other_order) { create(:order) }

specify do
   expect(describe_class.for_ids_with_order([order.id])).to eq [order]
   expect(describe_class.for_ids_with_order([other_order.id])).to eq [other_order]
end
```

Then, you can do another context that will test the ordering: I'd create 3 or more items, with specified positions and make an expectation like above but you're expecting an array of few items with a particular order (I'm not 100% sure what `"position((',' || id::text || ',') in ?)"` is doing there, hence no example. But this should get you going).

BTW. if it was a scope, I'd test it exactly the same way.

EDIT: I missed the part about retutning AR relation.

```
expect(describe_class.for_ids_with_order([order.id])).to be_a(ActiveRecord::Relation)
```